# Помогите!!!! Что это?

Tags: html

Я смотрел код сайта онлайн-игры, и увидел это(я внизу вставил код с фото). Что это чёрное? Можно ли это как-то открыть отдельно от кода сайта?

```
<a href="https://ibb.co/489zBfj"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/489zBfj/Screenshot-20221230-123315-Browser.jpg" alt="Screenshot-20221230-123315-Browser" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос странный... Но все мы учимся. Этот черный текст находится в блоке `<style>` и определяет стили остальных элементов сайта, используя CSS (язык стилей).

Он выделился черным, так как по умолчанию ваш редактор/браузер "раскрашивает" только HTML код.

Comment: Покорнейше благодарю